# How to authenticate using private key - Walmart Affiliate

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, walmart-api

I'm trying to use the Walmart Affiliate API, which uses a public/private token for authentication. I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm missing from the steps [provided](https://walmart.io/docs/affiliate/onboarding-guide).

I currently have a `DelegatingHandler` to add the Headers values needed. I'm using BouncyCastle to help in the private token signing and this is what I have currently.

```
    public static string Generate(string version, string consumerId, string timestamp)
    {
        // Canonicalize the headers, following after the java code in the docs.
        string[] canonicalStrings = Canonicalize(version, consumerId, timestamp);

        // Read the file with the password protected private key
        StreamReader stream= new StreamReader(@"..\key");
        PasswordFinder finder = new PasswordFinder("1234");

        // Actually get the private key
        PemReader pemReader= new PemReader(stream, finder);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
        RSAParameters rsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private);
        
        // Create the RSA Provider and import the private key
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        provider.ImportParameters(rsa);

        // Sign the canonicalized data
        byte[] signedData = provider.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalStrings[1]), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        // Convert the bytes to a base-64 string.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
    }

    private static string[] Canonicalize(string version, string consumerId, string timestamp)
    {
        // Follow after the java code, which just orders the keys/values.
        StringBuilder keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        SortedDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>() { { Constants.HEADER_COMSUMER_ID, consumerId }, { Constants.HEADER_TIMESTAMP, timestamp }, { Constants.HEADER_KEY_VERSION, version } };

        foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            keyBuilder.Append($"{key.Trim()};");
            valueBuilder.AppendLine($"{dictionary[key].Trim()}");
        }

        return new string[] {keyBuilder.ToString(), valueBuilder.ToString()};
    }
```

This is called via my `DelegatingHandler` by:

```
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string version = _walmartConfig.CurrentValue.Version; // Get Version from config
        string consumerId = _walmartConfig.CurrentValue.StageConsumerId; // Get ConsumerID from config
        string timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
        string signature = Generator.Generate(version, consumerId, timestamp); // Generate signature

        request.Headers.Add(Constants.HEADER_KEY_VERSION, version);
        request.Headers.Add(Constants.HEADER_COMSUMER_ID, consumerId);
        request.Headers.Add(Constants.HEADER_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
        request.Headers.Add(Constants.HEADER_SIGNATURE, signature);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

It's kicked off via an example call as mentioned in the [docs](https://walmart.io/docs/affiliate/quick-start-guide):

```
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://developer.api.walmart.com/api-proxy/service/affil/product/v2/taxonomy"))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request); // This returns HTTP 401.

            return response.Content.ToString();
        }
```

My private key was generated following the steps mentioned [here](https://walmart.io/key-tutorial) for Windows, but I exported the private key using the PuTTy menu item: Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key

That private key file looks something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,F014B20CAD95382A

0CE3...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I think I'm following the guide correctly, but I am still getting HTTP 401's from their API. Can anybody figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by mainly using the OpenSSL key creation through a unix terminal, but here's the final product if it helps anybody else.

Usage:

```
string signature = Signer.SignData(Signer.Canonicalize(version, consumerId, timestamp)[1], _keyManager.Key);
```

`_keyManager.Key` is found by using BouncyCastle to read the password protected private key.

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("c:\key.pem");
PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr, new PasswordFinder("123"));
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters keyPair = pr.ReadObject() as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
return DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair);
```

Finally the `Signer.SignData` implementation.

```
public static string SignData(string message, RSAParameters privateKey)
{
    byte[] signedBytes;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] originalBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        try
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);

            signedBytes = rsa.SignData(originalBytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);
}
```

To confirm it works I used the public key to verify. The fetching of the public key is similar to the private.

```
public static bool Verify(string originalData, string base64SignedData, RSAParameters publicKey)
{
    bool success = false;
    byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64SignedData);
    byte[] bytesToVerify = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalData);

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        try
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
            SHA256 sha256 = new SHA256Managed();

            byte[] hashedData = sha256.ComputeHash(signedBytes);

            success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signedBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Putting it all together as a test:

```
public void SignTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string version = "1";
    string consumerId = "8644d500-eyue-47gh-9b2b-54d5a4b9d45t";
    string timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();

    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\privateKey.pem");
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(sr, new PasswordFinder("123"));
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters keyPair = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();
    RSAParameters rsaPrivateParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyPair);

    StreamReader sr2 = File.OpenText(@"C:\publicKey.pem");
    PemReader pr2 = new PemReader(sr2, new PasswordFinder("123"));
    var keyPair2 = pr2.ReadObject();
    RSAParameters rsaPublicParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)keyPair2);

    string[] canonicalForm = Signer.Canonicalize(version, consumerId, timestamp);
    
    // Act
    string signedData = Signer.SignData(canonicalForm[1], rsaPrivateParameters);
    bool validated = Signer.Verify(canonicalForm[1], signedData, rsaPublicParameters);

    // Assert
    Assert.True(validated);
}
```